# Java GUI - JList won't display

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've encountered a bit of a weird issue. Basically there's a part of my program that sets and updates a list and it displays just fine, but when I use the same code in a another part of my program, it doesn't.

So what I'm trying to do is display a list of names in a JList when a button is clicked (after the program is run and frame already loaded), and the JList component just refuses to display anything.

The only difference in the working set of code and this one, is that this code is in a try catch (which is needed for my client server code). I know it's not a client server issue, but I need the try catch for that part of my code.

Here is my code (the commented out stuff are some of my attempts at fixing the issue, but to no avail yet):

```
JList<String> lReceivedlClient1Files = new JList<String>();

//String[] FakeList = new String[1];
//FakeList[0] = "No files to display yet";
//lReceivedlClient1Files.setListData(FakeList);

JButton btnFileList = new JButton("Request file list");
btnFileList.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        try
        {

            ////other client server code is here////

            int Counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0;i<NamesList.length;i++)
            {
                LeecherSocket.receive(TheNamePacket);
                TheName = new String(TheNameBuffer);

                NamesList[Counter] = TheName;
                Counter+=1;
            }

            lReceivedlClient1Files.setListData(NamesList);
            //lReceivedlClient1Files.setModel(NamesList);
            //lReceivedlClient1Files = new JList(NamesList);
            //validate();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SocketException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

LeecherPanel.add(lblFileList);
LeecherPanel.add(btnFileList);
LeecherPanel.add(lReceivedlClient1Files);

add(LeecherPanel);

pack();
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You should take a look at [MCVE] and [ask]

Comment: I understand, but I don't believe this error to be so big that it would need to reproduced and tested. I'm more just looking for suggestions on others ways I could possibly display my arrays data in my JList so that it can actually display..

Comment: You have some code, you have some unexpected behaviour. The most productive way to have others help you with it is to let them reproduce it. A decent [MCVE] might also let you figure out the problem yourself since it isolates the issue.

Comment: (1-) First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some names are correct others are not. `I don't believe this error to be so big` - Until the problem is found you have no idea how big the error is. If you actually add data to the ListModel and if you actually add the JList to a panel then the data should show. The problem is with your data or your code you didn't show. Post a proper `MCVE` that demonstrates the problem. And we don't have access to your real data so you need to simulate getting data by hardcoding it.

Comment: Also, code that blocks, like a Socket should not be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You should be using a SwingWorker for something like this. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: General tip. Add the list when the GUI is initialised. Populate the model on button click. If that does not work for your code, add an MCVE as suggested 8 hours ago. *"I don't believe this error to be so big that it would need to reproduced and tested"* When you can't solve the problem, what you believe is irrelevant. You're asking for **our help** & most of us won't give a question careful consideration until the code is compiled & run in our IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to create an instance of an interface:

> `btnFileList.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
>   {
>       @Override
>       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
>       {...`

See [docs on ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)

What you probably want to do is create a nested class that implements ActionListener (remember that you implement interfaces, whereas you extend classes). Example of something that doesn't work in a similar way to yours:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonTest {
    JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonTest gui = new ButtonTest();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button test");
        button = new JButton("clik meh pl0x");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String buttonText = button.getText();
                buttonText += " <teehee>";
                button.setText(buttonText);
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
        frame.setSize(1000,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

How to fix it with a nested class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonTest {
    JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonTest gui = new ButtonTest();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button test");
        button = new JButton("clik meh pl0x");

        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
        frame.setSize(1000,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String buttonText = button.getText();
                buttonText += " <teehee>";
                button.setText(buttonText);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the output after compiling, running, and several clicks:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMUCJ.png)